# why is it making the request twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, httpwebrequest

this code is written to send request to a service and receive simple json response but the service's server log shows that it is being requested twice with a delay of 1 second. I cant figure it out why does this code make the request twice please guide me if there is some configuration missing.

```
string StrUrl = @"http://www.myapp.com/Tracker.json";
Uri uri1 = new Uri(StrUrl);
HttpWebRequest webRequest1 = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri1);
webRequest1.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 1;
webRequest1.Timeout = 50000;
webRequest1.ReadWriteTimeout = 50000
webRequest1.PreAuthenticate = false;
webRequest1.Proxy = null;
webRequest1.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
webRequest1.Method = "POST";
webRequest1.KeepAlive = false;

WebResponse response1 = webRequest1.GetResponse();

StreamReader streamReader1 = new StreamReader(response1.GetResponseStream());
String responseData1 = streamReader1.ReadToEnd();
```

these might be similar problems

[Why my Http client making 2 requests when I specify credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338942/why-my-http-client-making-2-requests-when-i-specify-credentials?rq=1)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dad87752-42dd-4346-a1c5-da30f6156406/why-httpwebrequest-send-data-twice-in-https

Comment: Looks good. Maybe you call to the function twice?

Comment: check your code to see if you are calling the function twice.

Comment: i have tested the code with a break point in debugger. it runs only once

Comment: the service's server is tomcat running on centos 6 maybe there is some kind of compatibility issue ?

Comment: Check if any 401 challenge based authentication is used, as that will record two requests, and indeed two requests are sent.

Comment: You cannot disable authentication at client side, but you can enable pre-authentication, so that only one request is sent.

Comment: @Saifee It is a property of `HttpWebRequest` I think.

Comment: I solved my problem by using RestSharp (Simple REST and HTTP API Client for .NET)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem solved by using [RestSharp (Simple REST and HTTP API Client for .NET)](http://restsharp.org).

```
var client = new RestClient("http://www.myapp.com/Tracker.json");
// client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);

var request = new RestRequest("", Method.POST);

// execute the request
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
```

read this article for comparison of WebClient, HttpClient and HttpWebRequest