# C# .net How to cancel/abort the web request started by GetAsync, the cancellation token passed in it only cancels the task not the actual rquest

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

i am using `getAsync` method of `HttpClient` in .net c# to make a web request, as below, when i use `cancellationTokenSourceForTagDetails.cancel()` it only cancels the task but not the request, in fiddler i can still see the request sent by this call shows as pending only this cancel does is, it doesn't send second request. **how to cancel or abort the web request instead of just cancelling task** in .net c# using HttpClient class

```
 var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true, PreAuthenticate = true });
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var result = string.Empty;
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponceMessage = null;
        ViewApplicationDiagnostics.LogTrace("GetTags Request URL is " + path);

        try
        {
            httpResponceMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(path, cancellationTokenSourceForTagDetails.Token);
            //httpResponceMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(path);

            if (httpResponceMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                result = await httpResponceMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                ViewApplicationDiagnostics.LogWarning("Request failed, status code is = " + httpResponceMessage.StatusCode);
                throw new Exception("Request failed with HTTP status code " + httpResponceMessage.StatusCode);
            }

        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
        {
            ViewApplicationDiagnostics.LogTrace(ex.ToString());
            throw ex;
        }
```

Comment: When request was send to the server - you cannot to cancel it anymore. Unless you have access to the source code on the server side

Comment: "it doesn't send second request." Can you elaborate on that? Are you expecting a second request to be sent for some reason?

Comment: yes, i am using the basic authentication and in the basic authentication, it send first request without the authentication details and when that fails it again sends another request with authentication details. only this it does is that it doesnt send second rquest..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338942/why-my-http-client-making-2-requests-when-i-specify-credentials