# Using DefaultRequestHeaders sends requests twice?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a WebAPI that sends BASIC authorization information as following.

```
var client = new HttlpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(GlobalConstants.LdapUri);
var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", userName, password))));
Task<HttpResponseMessage> results = client.GetAsync(GlobalConstants.FortressAPIUriDev);
var response = await results;
```

I've built this API using MVC Core 1.x and the receiving API is built using MVC5.

The problem is that this GetAsync sends two requests at the same time, and I have no clue how to resolve this. I've done some Googling myself to see if I can find a fix for this but so far no luck. Did anyone experience this problem and know how to resolve it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The error is somewhere else. Need more info.

Comment: @PoulBak Thank you for your comment, but what other information should I provide?

Comment: Can it possibly be two requests from client at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I found a few postings talking about similar issues. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338942/why-my-http-client-making-2-requests-when-i-specify-credentials

Comment: Then it's a different question. I suggest you post some JavaScript.

Comment: But I have no Javascript written for this. It's all in C#

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, found a solution as follows:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, GlobalConstants.LdapUri + GlobalConstants.FortressAPIUriDev);
    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", userName, password))));
    var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
}
```

After replacing with this code, it is sending one request at a time.
Found a hint at : 
[Adding headers when using httpClient.GetAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801195/adding-headers-when-using-httpclient-getasync)